# Laravel 5.3 : Error when PHP Artisan Migrate install passport

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I'm quite new to Laravel. I'm trying to create API for my website. I hit this error when trying to install Passport into my project.

I exactly follow this tutorial 
[this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport)

I have run into this error when try to run the migrate command
[cmd screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGOmZ.png)

I'm not sure what cause this error as the tables are the default tables.

Thank you

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? And did you modify any of the files - like the DB migrations?

Comment: Check your migration carefully. You mistake comma or parenthesis closing.

Comment: I'm using 5.6.19. I didn't modify any other files.  All should be only default files.

Comment: I'm not sure which file to check on this error as I didn't add any file for this.